# How can I insert extra spaces to align code in the Visual Basic Editor?

Tags: microsoft-excel, visual-basic

I’d like to add spaces to align the “=” in this:

[image: unaligned text]

To get something that looks like the alignment of “As” in this:

[image: aligned text]

When I try to add spaces to align the “=”s, the Visual Basic Editor removes them as soon as I leave the line.  Curiously, it does not remove the spaces when I add them to the lines that begin with Dim.    How can I get the Visual Basic Editor to allow me my spaces?

Comment: See:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955809/how-can-i-prevent-the-vba-editor-from-removing-internal-whitespace

Comment: It's not generally good practice to do that anyway

Answer (score 0):

That's bad practice. Alternatively, consider grouping types together, but only when it improves readability.

```vb
Dim etime as Long
Dim temparr as Variant
Dim begin as Boolean, gapsFlag as Boolean
```